# In Ruby how to get the value in hash without the key?

Tags: ruby

```
def hand_score(hand)
  cards = {"A" => 4, "K" => 3, "Q" => 2, "J" => 1}
  score = 0

  hand.each_char do |char|
    score += cards[char.upcase]
  end
  return score
end

puts hand_score("AQAJ") #=> 11
puts hand_score("jJka") #=> 9
```

How does `cards[char.upcase]` 
evaluate to the number in the hash not to the string?

```
cards{"A" => 4}
```

How does `cards[char]` evaluate to the number 4 not to the letter "A" ??

Comment: Because this is how Ruby hash works? I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: Maybe you can consider to take a look to the docs: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Hash.html

Comment: I don't understand how cards[char]                       #how it evaluates to the number(value) in the hash

Comment: Thanks, guys the Ruby-dec was helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby Hash is working as expected but perhaps you don't understand the code you've provided.

```
cards = {"A" => 4, "K" => 3, "Q" => 2, "J" => 1}
```

In this example the letters ARE the keys and the numbers are the values.  To get a value, you call the key like this:

```
cards['A'] # this will return 4

hand.each_char # this is iterating over each character that is passed as a single string argument to your method.

 hand.each_char do |char| # char is just the iterator assigned inside the loop 
   score += cards[char.upcase] 
 end
```

A variable can be used instead of the string which is what's happening inside the loop.

```
char = 'a'
cards[char] # this will return nil because the keys were defined in upper case.
cards[char.upcase] # this will return 4 because the key is found when it is upper case.
```

For more see [documentation on Hash class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Hash.html)